# XPath matching leaf nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to write an XPath expression that returns true if it is a leaf node..

How can I achieve this..

```
//a[not(node()]
```

something like this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression that returns true if and only if the context node has no children is:

```
not(child::node())
```

Answer (score 2):

Text etc. is also nodes, therefore you probably want this:

```
not(*)
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer has been accepted, because it is wrong. It's true for a node that has no element node children. But the normal definition of a "leaf" node would be a node that has no children at all, of any kind. Unless of course the questioner and the answerer were both using the word "node" to mean "element"??

Comment: @MichaelKay, I agree with you on the terminology issue. However, given the way the question is worded I made the assumption that not any node but element nodes were meant, e.g. testing that a node is a leaf element. That's why I stated "you probably want this" - and not "this is the answer".